# Como alterar elementos de forma dinâmica através de Checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

Galera estou com um problema onde preciso fazer um função com parâmetros visando se um checkbox está marcado ou não. Eu consegui fazer para outro campo, mas este era estático, agora preciso fazer para elementos que serão dinamicamente adicionados através de um button. A questão é a seguinte, tenho em minha DIV "produtos" um campo de nome do produto, onde este por padrão vem com um `<select>`populado com produtos já cadastrados no BD através do jQuery e PHP e embaixo um checkbox para marcar caso o produto não esteja cadastrado, e ao ser marcado, aparece um campo input no lugar do select para digitar o nome do Produto. Como eu posso fazer isso, visando que outras DIV's de produtos podem ser adicionadas pelo usuário clicando no button de add e que, cada checkbox marcado deve apenas sumir com o select e mostrar o input em seu próprio campo ?

index.php:

```
                <div class="container" id="produtos">
                    <div class="separator"></div>

                    <div class="title-padrao">
                        <h1 class="text-center">
                            Produtos
                        </h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="allProducts">
                        <div class="produtos-wrap" name="produtos-wrap"> <!---- DIV A SER CLONADA / ADICIONADA !---->
                            <div class=" text-center select_height primeira">
                                <b>Item:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input type="text" class="index font-pop input-div" id="index_produto"
                                       name="index_produto[]" value="1" readonly="true">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height segunda">
                                <b>ID:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input class="font-pop number_id_produto input-div" value="0" readonly="true"
                                       name="id_produto[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="select-produto select_height terceira">
                                <b>Selecione um produto:</b>
                                <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-show-subtext="false"
                                        data-live-search="true" name="select_produtos[]" id="select_produtos"
                                        onchange="initProdutos(this)">
                                    <?php

                                    echo '<option disabled selected hidden value="Selecione um produto..." data-subtext="Selecione um produto...">Selecione um produto...</option>';

                                    foreach ($result2 as $item_produtos) {
                                        echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '" value="'
                                            . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '">' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                                <input type="text" class="" name="produto_new_input" id="produto_new_input"
                                   style="display: none">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="change_produto" name="change_produto[]"
                                   value="Fornecedor não cadastrado">&nbsp;
                                <label for="change_produto" id="checkbox-produto-text">Produto não cadastrado</label>

                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height quarta">
                                <b>Embalagem:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="edit-input font-pop" name="embalagem[]"
                                       value="">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height quinta">
                                <b>Preço:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input type="number" id="preco-input" name="preco[]"
                                       oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" min="0" class="edit-input font-pop"
                                       value="0">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height sexta">
                                <b>Quantidade:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input type="number" id="qtd-input" oninput="this.value = Math.abs(this.value)" min="0"
                                       class="edit-input font-pop"
                                       value="0" name="quantidade-produto[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height text-right setima">
                                <b>Preço do Produto:</b>
                                <br>
                                <input class="font-pop preco-produto input-div" readonly="true" name="preco-produto[]">
                            </div>

                            <div class="text-center select_height oitava" id="div-remove">
                                <button type="button"
                                        class="remover glyphicon glyphicon-remove button-produto"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="add-button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign button-produto"></button>
                </div>
```

Função JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[name='change_produto[]']").on('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("div.btn-group.bootstrap-select.form-control").children().eq(0).css("display", "none");
            $("#produto_new_input").css("display", "block");
        } else {
            $("div.btn-group.bootstrap-select.form-control").children().eq(0).css("display", "block");
            $("#produto_new_input").css("display", "none");
        }
    })
})
```

OBS: Este campo que setei no JQuery é o unico que faz sumir de fato com o SELECT, pois é o mesmo que aparece como campo full no Inspecionar Elemento, como mostra a seguinte imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Função de Clone():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clone = $('#allProducts').html().replace(/<b>.*?<\/b>|<br>/g, "");
    $(document).on('click', '#add-button', addProd);

    $(document).on('click', '.remover', function () {
        $(this).parents('.produtos-wrap').remove();
        ids();
        calculos();
    });

    function addProd() {
        $('#allProducts').append(clone);
        ids();
        $(".produtos-wrap[i]").addClass("p-all");
    }

    function ids() {
        $("[name='index_produto[]']").each(function (i, e) {
            $(e).val(i + 1);
        });
    }
});
```

Pós edit:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta alterando para `$(document).on('change', '[name="change_produto[]"]', function(){`

Comment: Não deu certo @Sam, antes ele tava habilitando o Input mas dando display:none em outro elemento; agora não está fazendo nenhum dos dois.

Comment: Mas vc está clocando objetos e repetindo id's. Não vai funcionar com id's porque um id não pode ser repetido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está clonando uma div que possui alguns elementos com id's. Um id não pode ser repetido na mesma página. Por exemplo, no caso da label do checkbox onde o atributo `for` referencia a id do checkbox, não vai funcionar nos elementos clonados porque vai sempre referenciar ao primeiro id do primeiro checkbox. Ao clonar a div, você deveria criar um id dinâmico para cada checkbox e no `for` dos labels. Bom, isso é algo que deveria ser consertado.

Também o `name` dos inputs que irão substituir os selects também deveriam ser em forma de array já que poderão ser vários, ou seja, em vez de `name="produto_new_input"` deveria ser `name="produto_new_input[]"`.

Em relação a mostrar/ocultar o select e o input ao marcar o checkbox, o código abaixo faz isso mesmo com elementos dinâmicos. Basta buscar os elementos pela div pai. Não precisa usar id's para isso:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', "[name='change_produto[]']", function(){

       var sel = $(this).closest("div").find(".bootstrap-select");

        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this)
            .closest("div")
            .find(sel.length ? ".bootstrap-select" : "select")
            .hide()
            .end()
            .find("[name='produto_new_input[]']")
            .show();
        } else {
            $(this)
            .closest("div")
            .find(sel.length ? ".bootstrap-select" : "select")
            .show()
            .end()
            .find("[name='produto_new_input[]']")
            .hide();
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: está solução está funcionando para as DIV's que são adicionadas, mas para a primeira que ja vem de padrão não funciona, devido a classe do Bootstrap. Como consigo resolver isso ? Vou editar a pergunta com as imagens.

Comment: Pronto @Sam, editei a pergunta com a mesma.

Comment: Altera essa linha: `.closest("div")` para ``.closest("div.select-produto")``

Comment: Alterei e não mudou @Sam, vou testar colocando a da classe do Bootstrap.

Comment: Em primeiro modo ele funcionou, mas ao desmarcar o checkbox, ele continua bugado. Editei novamente a pergunta com as imagens.

Comment: Editei a resposta novamente.

Comment: Agora deu certo, muito obrigado @Sam !!!!

Comment: Sam me desculpe o transtorno e até o tempo que tomei para vim falar a respeito, mas há alguma maneira de eu também mudar o valor do campo de ID do produto quando eu marcar / desmarcar o checkbox ? Preciso mudar o valor do mesmo por alguns motivos que surgiram por aqui. Tentei fazer seguindo a mesma lógica dos inputs, mas não deu certo.

Comment: Vc quer mudar o texto na coluna ID?

Comment: Sim, no caso o valor do ```<input class="font-pop number_id_produto input-div" value="0" readonly="true" name="id_produto[]">```. Se o checkbox estiver marcado quero colocar um número, e se desmarcar ele volta pra 0, por exemplo.

Comment: Tenta adicionando `.end().find(".number_id_produto").val(número que vc quer)`

Comment: Tentei e não deu certo Sam. Com essa forma já até tinha tentado antes sozinho mas não deu certo.

Comment: Tenta pelo name: `.end().find("[name='id_produto[]']").val(número que vc quer)`

Comment: vai ficar assim: https://jsfiddle.net/9r8osnw7/

Comment: Testei aqui e também não deu certo, ele não muda o campo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96936/discussion-between-sam-and-leo-faleiros).